# Error check, looking for some guidance

Tags: c, arrays

I have a text file with with 100 random numbers, 1 line at a time. I have an array that reads each line and stores each number into every element of my array. Array size is initially 1000. I have a maxSize that is defined as 10. This maxSize acts as a memory size.

So when maxSize is 10, I could only fit 10 numbers from the text file into the array. If its greater than max I need to print out (too big).

In other words when the text file attempts to store more numbers that exceed maxSize I need to print out an error message like printf("too big");

If I have a text file with less than 10 numbers, there is no problem.

Im not too sure on how to tackle this error check in my program I thought by comparing all of the numbers in the array to max. But I am having some trouble figuring the algorithm out.

Error check is in my last function, the code there is wrong not sure how to compare maxSize to array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 1000 /*Array size*/
#define INIT_MEMO 50505 /*Toke*/
#define END -999999 /*End of file*/
#define TOO_BIG -10
#define INVALID_WORD -20

void init_memo(int a[]);
void dump (int accumulaotr, int instcounter, int instregister, int operationcode, int operand);
void dump_memo( int a[], int max );
int load();
int error_message(int [], int);

int main( void ) {
int memory[SIZE];   

int opCode = 00;        
int op = 000;           
int instreg = 00000; 
int instctr = 000; 
int acc = 000000; 
int ints = 0;       

int maxmemo = 0;    
int *mem;           
int on = 0; 

init_memo(memory);  dump(acc, instctr, instreg, opCode, op);
printf("ValidInstruction\t%d\n", ++ints);

dump(acc, instctr, instreg, opCode, op);
printf("ValidInstructions\t%d\n", ++ints);
dump_memo(memory, 10); 
error_message(memory, 10);
return EXIT_SUCCESS
}

void init_memo( int a[] ) {
 int i;

 for(i = 0; i < SIZE-1; i++){ /*Initialize all array values to 50505*/
     a[i] = INIT_MEMO;
}
}

 void dump (int accumulaotr, int instcounter, int instregister, int                 operationcode, int operand) {
printf("\n");
printf("REGISTERS:\n");
printf("accumulator\t\t%+05d\n", accumulaotr);
printf("instructioncounter\t%03d\n", instcounter);
printf("instructionregister\t%+05d\n", instregister);
printf("operationcode\t\t%02d\n", operationcode);
printf("operand\t\t\t%03d\n", operand);
}


void dump_memo( int a[], int max ) {
int i;
int count = 0;

load(a); 

printf("\n");
printf("\n");
printf("MEMORY:\n");
printf("\n");
printf("  %d ", count);
for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++) { 
        printf("%+d ", a[i]);
}

count +=10;
printf("\n %d ", count);
for(i = 10; i < max; i++) { 
        printf("%+d ", a[i]);
}
printf("\n");

}


int load(int mem[]) {
int num;
int i = 0;
char c;
while ( fscanf( stdin, "%d%c", &num, &c) == 2) {    
    if (num != END) {
        mem[i] = num; 
    }   
    i++;        
}
return 0;
}   

int error_message(int a[], int max) {
int size = 0;
size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
printf("%d\n", size);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: post the code so far

Comment: "In other words when the text file attempts to store ..." OOP at it's best? Most text files cannot store something themself. Please show the code of that file.

Comment: maybe its a smart file ;)

Comment: @amdixon i added my code.

Comment: That is no code, but a mess. Please format it! You should make some effort at least to present your problem properly!

Comment: Where do you open the file ? What's the name of the file ?

Comment: @moehajer, however you are reading your file, just keep a counter (e.g. `size_t cnt = 0;`) then as you read each line and add a value to your array, just increment the count (e.g. `cnt++;` or `cnt += 1;`)  If you are using a for loop, the loop index can serve as your counter (save it in `cnt` after you read your last value into your array). While you are reading, in whatever loop you use, `if (cnt == max) { printf ("Too Big!\n"); break; }`

Answer (score 0):

Refer to David C. Rankin's comment above. Since you already have a counter `i`, insert `if (i == max) { printf ("Too Big!\n"); break; }` before the line

```
        mem[i] = num;
```

of course you have to pass `max` to the `load()` function.